# Определенный стиль цифр в Android-приложении

Tags: android, css

Мне необходимо выводить таймер, и нужно что бы стиль цифр был как у многих часов. На подобие этого

[image]

Так вот, можно ли подобный стиль задать цифрам, средствами Android?
Или только если самому на каждую цифру изображения приготовить и ими отрисовывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Находим в интернете нужный шрифт (сайтов хватает)
2. Создаем папку assets/fonts и ложем их туда в формате ttf

   ```
   Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myFont.ttf");
   ```
3. Применяем

   ```
   TextView.setTypeface()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, будет значительно быстрее и проще нарисовать эти цифры в фотошопе (любом другом любимом редакторе). Всего то 10 цифр и двоеточие. (хотя двоеточие лучше рисовать на подложке - то есть, 10 цифр и подложка). Это даст приимущество, что в будущем можно будет просто  добавить две картинки (цифры можно нарисовать на одной картинке) и получить новый стиль.

Более того, используя встроенные средства drawable (shape), можно все эти изображения цифр построить на базе xml - они будут хорошо масштабироваться и расскрашиваться.